# Unexpected T_VARIABLE error when inserting into DB

Tags: php, sql

HTML form connectivity to database error shows ob insert into table line code in PHP file:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients_info 
(Name,Organisation,Contact,Email,Services_Vertical,Comments) VALUES 
("$name","$organisation",$contact,"$email","$service","$comment")";
```

The error message is:

```
Error: 
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

Comment: You messed up your distribution of `"`. Any decent editor will show you where.

Answer (score 1):

As @sirko mentioned your quotation marks are incorrect. See below:

```
 <?php

 $sql= "INSERT INTO clients_info (Name,Organisation,Contact,Email,Services_Vertical,Comments) VALUES ('".$name."','".$organisation."','".$contact."','".$email."','".$service."','".$comment."')";

 ?>
```